# jQuery val or javascript changing value, validate the field even if the value don't match with the Validation Properties

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Element Example:

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="presentation" required="" minlength="10" maxlength="300"></textarea>
```

If manually, insert any text, the validation is set to Valid if the length is between 10 and 300 chars.

Example:
if i manually write "Hello" on the field and run:

```
$('#presentation')[0].validity.valid
/*will return "false" as expected*/
```

but if i use any of this way to change the value of the field:

```
 $('#presentation').prop('value','hell')
//or
 $('#presentation').val('hell')
//or
 $('#presentation')[0].value='hello'
```

It will cause:

```
$('#presentation')[0].validity.valid
/*will return "true" and will cause a validation problem*/
```

it set the field to valid, and the only way to revalidate is to change the value in the field, manually.
this will cause that invalid data could be submitted in the form this field will not be checked.

This is happening in Chrome, firefox, edge and opera.

do you know if there's anyway to force the field to validate his value?

here a fiddler with this problem:
https://jsfiddle.net/rfigueiredo/jnuhfsc7/20/

Comment: Programmatical change to the value of the textarea doesn't fire any events.

Comment: Ok but changes made programmatically, seems to allways set the validity of the field to true doesn't matter what value you send or what validity properties the field has.

Comment: Are you using some commonly known validation library? If so, please provide the name (and link to the documentation), or if it's your own, add the code to the post.

Comment: I thought this could be fixed by triggering `onchange` or `oninput` after the changing of value, but weirdly enough it doesn't seem to work. As far as my research went I didn't find any way to force a validation...

Comment: Teemu, is the default of html5 ecs6. An element inside the form. E-Telier I tried that trigger on change, key up press and  down events no result